# Outlook AddIn - change the GlobalAppointmentId

Tags: outlook, vsto, netoffice

Is there a way to change the GlobalAppointmentId of an appointment.

I found this property schema:

```
var globalIdPropertySchema = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{6ED8DA90-450B-101B-98DA-00AA003F1305}/00030102";
```

and I set a new value to it:

```
Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(globalIdPropertySchema, MY_NEW_ID);
```

then when I get it using `Item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` I'm getting the new id, but the `Item.GlobalAppointmentId` is still the original one.

I'm needing this so that my addin can sync appointments using ICS files, our system sends ICS files with a suffix in the iCalendar UID field.
But it's possible to create appointments for our system through the Outlook AddIn, then the ICS file which is send uses the GlobalAppointmentID as the UID field in the ICS file. We store it, but it needs to have our suffix. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to completely release the appointment to make sure Outlook reloads it next time.

Do you see the change after you restart Outlook?

Comment: I don't see the change after an Outlook restart, it looks like the `Item.GlobalAppointmentId` is somewhere cached, is there a programmatical wway to release the object?

Comment: Are you sure the id is set to a properly constructed value? Can you see the change in OutlookSpy (click IMessage) after you call AppointmentItem.Save?

Comment: I forgot to call `Appointment.Save` after `SetProperty`, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Quick question @dmitry-streblechenko the `SetProperty` throws a `The operation failed.` exception in Outlook 2010, any tips how to change the global id in that version?

Comment: on Outlook 2010 always, on newer never.

Comment: I can only suggest trying to use Extended MAPI (++ or Delphi) or Redemption.

Comment: I'm using the netoffice library, does the mentioned ways have more capabilities?

Comment: I am not familiar with netoffice, sorry.

Comment: So with Extended MAPI or Redemption setting the global ID shouldn't be a problem in Outlook 2010?

Comment: Yes, that will work - OOM tries to be a Big Brother and tries to protect the developer for shooting himself in the foot.